# Why removing this element from an object inside an Angular service doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, javascript-objects

I'm creating an app using Angularjs and I'm trying to use an object as a arrays container; so I have objects->array->objects. I can use an array as the container instead, I know, but it doesn't seem to work properly that way. I have a service containing the object, and two methods to add and delete entries. Adding works perfect, but deletion doesnt, even though I check out the console and  the output is **true** ($log.log(delete persons[person]);) ..

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

  app.controller('appController', function($log, $scope, MyService){
    $scope.users = MyService.getPersons();

    $scope.addEntry = function(){
      MyService.addEmail($scope.newPerson, $scope.newEmail);
    };
    $scope.deleteEntry = function(){
      MyService.deleteEmail($scope.personDelete);
    };
  });
  
  angular.module('app').service('MyService', function($log){
    var persons = {};
    this.addEmail = function(person, email){
      persons[person] =  persons[person]? persons[person] : []; 
      persons[person].push({id: email});
    };
    this.deleteEmail = function(person){
        //$log.log(delete persons[person]); <-- it's true!
      delete persons[person];
    };
    this.getPersons = function(){
      return persons;
    };
});
```

here's the Plunkr

https://plnkr.co/edit/yElSTpo4lsKz1VnIIGRx?p=preview

Comment: person is undefined inside deleteEmail function.
send the reference of person through deleteEntry function in html....deleteEntry(person)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ngModel on the TD element doesn't make sense and doesn't do anything. Just pass `person` object to deleteEntry method:

```
  <tbody ng-repeat="(person, emails) in users">
    <tr ng-repeat="email in emails">
      <td>{{person}}</td>
      <td>{{email.id}}</td>
      <td>
        <button ng-click="deleteEntry(person)">delete</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

and in controller:

```
$scope.deleteEntry = function(person) {
    MyService.deleteEmail(person);
};
```

**Demo:** https://plnkr.co/edit/q7HF4aaRGh0Cxq7yWqZz?p=preview